# Namenode not getting started

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was using Hadoop in a pseudo-distributed mode and everything was working fine. But then I had to restart my computer because of some reason. And now when I am trying to start Namenode and Datanode I can find only Datanode running. Could anyone tell me the possible reason of this problem? Or am I doing something wrong?

I tried both `bin/start-all.sh` and `bin/start-dfs.sh`.

Comment: i reformatted the HDFS and now i am able to start both Namonode and Datanode.but once i am using Hadoop for my project i can't reformat the HDFS..i need some permanent solution..

Answer (score 102):

I was facing the issue of namenode not starting. I found a solution using following:

1. first delete all contents from temporary folder: `rm -Rf <tmp dir>` (my was /usr/local/hadoop/tmp)
2. format the namenode: `bin/hadoop namenode -format`
3. start all processes again:`bin/start-all.sh`

You may consider rolling back as well using checkpoint (if you had it enabled).

Comment: @ketan: +1 helped me as well. Would like to know the cause of this though.

Comment: one can look for his/her temp location definition at conf/core-site.xml   at the time of setup you would have given some value to this tag <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>

Answer (score 37):

`hadoop.tmp.dir` in the core-site.xml is [defaulted](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml) to `/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}` which is cleaned after every reboot. Change this to some other directory which doesn't get cleaned on reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply Praveen.

Comment: Hello Praven, I had changed the hadoop.tmp.dir directory to /home/tariq/hadoop and everything was working fine..But today when I started my computer I could not start the datanode..I am facing exactly the same problem which I was facing earlier..The only difference is that this time it is datanode instead of namenode...Need your able guidance

Comment: The first thing when you face a problem is to do a bit of debugging and provide inputs (exceptions, logs etc) for others to help you. I don't see it done.

Comment: Hello Praveen..The problem is that the directory which I have specified for " dfs.data.dir " is being considered as invalid..Here is the error which I am getting in the datanode log file - 2011-11-11 19:31:25,448 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: All directories in dfs.data.dir are invalid.

Answer (score 26):

Following **STEPS** worked for me with hadoop 2.2.0,

**STEP 1** stop hadoop

```
hduser@prayagupd$ /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/sbin/stop-dfs.sh
```

**STEP 2** remove tmp folder

```
hduser@prayagupd$ sudo rm -rf /app/hadoop/tmp/
```

**STEP 3** create /app/hadoop/tmp/

```
hduser@prayagupd$ sudo mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp
hduser@prayagupd$ sudo chown hduser:hadoop /app/hadoop/tmp
hduser@prayagupd$ sudo chmod 750 /app/hadoop/tmp
```

**STEP 4** format namenode

```
hduser@prayagupd$ hdfs namenode -format
```

**STEP 5** start dfs

```
hduser@prayagupd$ /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

**STEP 6** check jps

```
hduser@prayagupd$ $ jps
11342 Jps
10804 DataNode
11110 SecondaryNameNode
10558 NameNode
```

Comment: Thanks Prayag. It works for me, Actually I was missed to format namenode.

Comment: I had the same symptoms, after trying all Prayag's  suggestions (which I found very well done btw) I still had the same symptoms.  Then I found this ... the dfs path on my Namenode was set to an external drive which I had inadvertently disconnected!  Oops.  Moral : check your drives/paths since I didn't find any obvious error messages indicating the path was invalid.

Answer (score 4):

In conf/hdfs-site.xml, you should have a property like

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/user/hadoop/name/data</value>
</property>
```

The property "dfs.name.dir" allows you to control where Hadoop writes NameNode metadata. 
And giving it another dir rather than /tmp makes sure the NameNode data isn't being deleted when you reboot.

Comment: I think you are missing file://

Comment: In Hadoop 3.0.0 this is at $HADOOP_ROOT/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml.

Answer (score 3):

Open a new terminal and start the namenode using *path-to-your-hadoop-install/bin/hadoop namenode*

The check using *jps* and namenode should be running

Answer (score 2):

Why do most answers here assume that all data needs to be deleted, reformatted, and then restart Hadoop?
How do we know namenode is not progressing, but taking lots of time.
It will do this when there is a large amount of data in HDFS.
Check progress in logs before assuming anything is hung or stuck.

```
$ [kadmin@hadoop-node-0 logs]$ tail hadoop-kadmin-namenode-hadoop-node-0.log

...
016-05-13 18:16:44,405 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader: replaying edit log: 117/141 transactions completed. (83%)
2016-05-13 18:16:56,968 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader: replaying edit log: 121/141 transactions completed. (86%)
2016-05-13 18:17:06,122 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader: replaying edit log: 122/141 transactions completed. (87%)
2016-05-13 18:17:38,321 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader: replaying edit log: 123/141 transactions completed. (87%)
2016-05-13 18:17:56,562 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader: replaying edit log: 124/141 transactions completed. (88%)
2016-05-13 18:17:57,690 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader: replaying edit log: 127/141 transactions completed. (90%)
```

This was after nearly an hour of waiting on a particular system.
It is still progressing each time I look at it.
Have patience with Hadoop when bringing up the system and check logs before assuming something is hung or not progressing.

Comment: After another 15 minutes of waiting I am now seeing this in my namenode log. "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". Would appear that namenode is hung because Java is out of memory.

Comment: Could you indicate the path to your logfile?

Answer (score 2):

In core-site.xml:

```
    <configuration>
       <property>
          <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
          <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
       </property>
       <property>
          <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
          <value>/home/yourusername/hadoop/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}
         </value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

and format of namenode with :

`hdfs namenode -format`

worked for hadoop 2.8.1

Answer (score 1):

If anyone using hadoop1.2.1 version and not able to run namenode, go to `core-site.xml`, and change `dfs.default.name` to `fs.default.name`.

And then format the namenode using `$hadoop namenode -format`.

Finally run the hdfs using `start-dfs.sh` and check for service using jps..

Answer (score 0):

Did you change `conf/hdfs-site.xml` `dfs.name.dir`?

Format namenode after you change it.

```
$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
$ bin/hadoop start-all.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you kept default configurations when running hadoop the port for the namenode would be 50070. You will need to find any processes running on this port and kill them first.

- Stop all running hadoop with : `bin/stop-all.sh`

  *check all processes running in port 50070*
- `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :50070`  #check any processes running in
  port    50070, if there are any the / will
  appear    at the RHS of the output.
- `sudo kill -9 <process_id> #kill_the_process`.
- `sudo rm -r /app/hadoop/tmp` #delete the temp folder
- `sudo mkdir /app/hadoop/tmp` #recreate it
- `sudo chmod 777 –R /app/hadoop/tmp` (777 is given for this example    purpose only)
- `bin/hadoop namenode –format` #format hadoop namenode
- `bin/start-all.sh` #start-all hadoop services

Refer [this blog](http://ranithsachin.blogspot.mx/2014/04/building-search-engine-with-nutch-solr.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you facing this issue after rebooting the system, Then below steps will work fine

For workaround.

1) format the namenode: `bin/hadoop namenode -format`

2) start all processes again:`bin/start-all.sh`

For Perm fix: -

1) go to  /conf/core-site.xml change fs.default.name to your custom one.

2) format the namenode: `bin/hadoop namenode -format`

3) start all processes again:`bin/start-all.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1) Stop all hadoop processes : `stop-all.sh`

2) Remove the tmp folder manually

3) Format namenode : `hadoop namenode -format`

4) Start all processes : `start-all.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem.

(1) Always check for the typing mistakes in the configuring the `.xml` files, especially the xml tags.

(2) go to **bin** dir. and type `./start-all.sh`

(3) then type `jps` , to check if processes are working

Answer (score 0):

For me the following worked after I changed the directory of the namenode 
and datanode in `hdfs-site.xml`

-- before executing the following steps stop all services with `stop-all.sh` or in my case I used the `stop-dfs.sh` to stop the dfs

1. On the new configured directory, for every node (namenode and datanode), delete every folder/files inside it (in my case a 'current' directory).
2. delete the Hadoop temporary directory: `$rm -rf /tmp/haddop-$USER`
3. format the Namenode: `hadoop/bin/hdfs namenode -format`
4. `start-dfs.sh`

After I followed those steps my namenode and datanodes were alive using the new configured directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add **hadoop.tmp.dir** property in core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/yourname/hadoop/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

and format hdfs (hadoop 2.7.1):

```
$ hdfs namenode -format
```

The default value in [core-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml) is /tmp/hadoop-${user.name}, which will be deleted after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If your namenode is stuck in safemode you can ssh to namenode, `su hdfs` user and run the following command to turn off safemode:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -fs hdfs://server.com:8020 -safemode leave
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran `$hadoop namenode` to start namenode manually at foreground.

From the logs I figured out that 50070 is ocuupied, which was defaultly used by dfs.namenode.http-address. After configuring dfs.namenode.http-address in hdfs-site.xml, everything went well.

Answer (score 0):

```
I got the solution just share with you that will work who got the errors:

1. First check the /home/hadoop/etc/hadoop path, hdfs-site.xml and

 check the path of namenode and datanode 

<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>

2.Check the permission,group and user of namenode and datanode of the particular path(/home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode), and check if there are any problems in all of them and if there are any mismatch then correct it. ex .chown -R hadoop:hadoop in_use.lock, change user and group

chmod -R 755 <file_name> for change the permission
```

Answer (score 0):

After deleting a resource managers' data folder, the problem is gone.
Even if you have formatting cannot solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of formatting namenode, may be you can use the below command to restart the namenode. It worked for me:

sudo service hadoop-master restart

2. hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue of namenode not starting with ***Hadoop-**3.2.1***** version. I did the steps to resolve the issue:

1. Delete the contents from temporary folder from the name node directory. In my case the "current" directory made by root user: rm -rf (dir name)
2. Format the namenode: hdfs namenode -format
3. start the processes again:start-dfs.sh

Point #1 has change in the hdfs-site.xml file.

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///opt/hadoop/node-data/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same thing after a restart.

for hadoop-2.7.3 all I had to do was format the namenode:

```
<HadoopRootDir>/bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

Then a jps command shows

```
6097 DataNode
755 RemoteMavenServer
5925 NameNode
6293 SecondaryNameNode
6361 Jps
```