# Errors on running hadoop example code

Tags: hadoop, runtime-error

I am trying to run the sample pi map-red example code. upon running in pseudo distributed mode the following error is occurring.  I have done all the setup as instructed in the hadoop site. I have ssh installed and the configuration files also properly set up.

```
hadoop_admin@ubuntu:~/hadoop-1.0.4$ sudo bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar pi 10 10
Number of Maps  = 10
Samples per Map = 10
13/02/13 14:47:34 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
13/02/13 14:47:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
13/02/13 14:47:36 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).
13/02/13 14:47:37 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 3 time(s).
13/02/13 14:47:38 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).
13/02/13 14:47:39 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 5 time(s).
13/02/13 14:47:40 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 6 time(s).
13/02/13 14:47:41 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 7 time(s).
13/02/13 14:47:42 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 8 time(s).
13/02/13 14:47:43 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 9 time(s).
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getWorkingDirectory(JobConf.java:546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.estimate(PiEstimator.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.run(PiEstimator.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.main(PiEstimator.java:351)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1099)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1075)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at $Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getWorkingDirectory(JobConf.java:542)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2000(Client.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1206)
    at org.apac
```

Can someone help me identify why the above errors are coming and how to rectify it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes when Datanode daemon on the system does not start.check the started daemons using "jps" command.If it in not started,start Datanode daemon manually by using the command:
bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode.

Comment: If the above comment does help you,try another thing.Delete your log file and the file which your entered in "dfs.data.dir" property file in hdfs.site.xml .Format the system and start all your daemons again.This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I referred the post on [Namenode not getting started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076439/namenode-not-getting-started) and I am able to fix the problem.

1. Delete the tmp directory which you set in core-site.xml.
2. hadoop name-node -format
3. start-dfs.sh or start-all.sh
4. jps