# Datanode starts but not namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

After a bit of struggling I had eventually managed to use hadoop in pseudo-distributed node, with a `namenode` and a `jobtracker` working perfectly (at `http://localhost:50070` and `http://localhost:50030`)

Yesterday I tried to restart my `namenode`, `datanode`, etc with:

```
$hadoop namenode -format
$start-all.sh
```

And `jps` gives me the following output:

```
17148 DataNode
17295 SecondaryNameNode
17419 JobTracker
17669 Jps
```

Namenode doesn't seem to be willing to start anymore ... And Jobtracker dies a few seconds later.

Mark that I hadn't restarted my computer and that I've tried the solution given in the following thread [Namenode not getting started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076439/namenode-not-getting-started) but it didn't help.

Here is the log of the namenode, with a bunch of errors. I don't know how to solve my issue at all

```
    2013-08-16 09:02:21,647 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = localhost.lan/192.168.1.94
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_25
************************************************************/
2013-08-16 09:02:21,839 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-08-16 09:02:21,868 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-08-16 09:02:21,871 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-08-16 09:02:21,871 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2013-08-16 09:02:22,098 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-08-16 09:02:22,103 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-08-16 09:02:22,110 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2013-08-16 09:02:22,111 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2013-08-16 09:02:22,140 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
2013-08-16 09:02:22,140 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2013-08-16 09:02:22,140 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2.0% max memory = 932118528
2013-08-16 09:02:22,140 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2013-08-16 09:02:22,140 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
2013-08-16 09:02:22,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=rlk
2013-08-16 09:02:22,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2013-08-16 09:02:22,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2013-08-16 09:02:22,189 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2013-08-16 09:02:22,189 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2013-08-16 09:02:22,271 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2013-08-16 09:02:22,320 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: dfs.namenode.edits.toleration.length = 0
2013-08-16 09:02:22,321 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2013-08-16 09:02:22,363 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Start loading image file /home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/fsimage
2013-08-16 09:02:22,364 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files = 1
2013-08-16 09:02:22,372 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files under construction = 0
2013-08-16 09:02:22,375 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file /home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/fsimage of size 109 bytes loaded in 0 seconds.
2013-08-16 09:02:22,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Start loading edits file /home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/edits
2013-08-16 09:02:22,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: EOF of /home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/edits, reached end of edit log Number of transactions found: 0.  Bytes read: 4
2013-08-16 09:02:22,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Start checking end of edit log (/home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/edits) ...
2013-08-16 09:02:22,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Checked the bytes after the end of edit log (/home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/edits):
2013-08-16 09:02:22,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog:   Padding position  = -1 (-1 means padding not found)
2013-08-16 09:02:22,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog:   Edit log length   = 4
2013-08-16 09:02:22,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog:   Read length       = 4
2013-08-16 09:02:22,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog:   Corruption length = 0
2013-08-16 09:02:22,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog:   Toleration length = 0 (= dfs.namenode.edits.toleration.length)
2013-08-16 09:02:22,382 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Summary: |---------- Read=4 ----------|-- Corrupt=0 --|-- Pad=0 --|
2013-08-16 09:02:22,382 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Edits file /home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/edits of size 4 edits # 0 loaded in 0 seconds.
2013-08-16 09:02:22,387 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file /home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/fsimage of size 109 bytes saved in 0 seconds.
2013-08-16 09:02:22,553 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: closing edit log: position=4, editlog=/home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/edits
2013-08-16 09:02:22,553 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: close success: truncate to 4, editlog=/home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/edits
2013-08-16 09:02:22,933 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameCache: initialized with 0 entries 0 lookups
2013-08-16 09:02:22,933 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Finished loading FSImage in 776 msecs
2013-08-16 09:02:22,935 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.safemode.threshold.pct          = 0.9990000128746033
2013-08-16 09:02:22,935 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
2013-08-16 09:02:22,935 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.safemode.extension              = 30000
2013-08-16 09:02:22,935 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of blocks excluded by safe block count: 0 total blocks: 0 and thus the safe blocks: 0
2013-08-16 09:02:22,956 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Total number of blocks = 0
2013-08-16 09:02:22,956 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of invalid blocks = 0
2013-08-16 09:02:22,956 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of under-replicated blocks = 0
2013-08-16 09:02:22,956 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of  over-replicated blocks = 0
2013-08-16 09:02:22,956 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Safe mode termination scan for invalid, over- and under-replicated blocks completed in 21 msec
2013-08-16 09:02:22,956 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Leaving safe mode after 0 secs
2013-08-16 09:02:22,956 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Network topology has 0 racks and 0 datanodes
2013-08-16 09:02:22,962 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* UnderReplicatedBlocks has 0 blocks
2013-08-16 09:02:22,972 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.HostsFileReader: Refreshing hosts (include/exclude) list
2013-08-16 09:02:22,974 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 1 msec
2013-08-16 09:02:22,974 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 1 msec processing time, 1 msec clock time, 1 cycles
2013-08-16 09:02:22,974 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 0 msec
2013-08-16 09:02:22,974 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 0 msec processing time, 0 msec clock time, 1 cycles
2013-08-16 09:02:22,983 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source FSNamesystemMetrics registered.
2013-08-16 09:02:23,026 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
2013-08-16 09:02:23,029 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort8020 registered.
2013-08-16 09:02:23,030 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort8020 registered.
2013-08-16 09:02:23,037 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Namenode up at: localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:8020
2013-08-16 09:02:23,195 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2013-08-16 09:02:23,306 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2013-08-16 09:02:23,318 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = false
2013-08-16 09:02:23,329 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50070
2013-08-16 09:02:23,331 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50070 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50070
2013-08-16 09:02:23,331 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50070
2013-08-16 09:02:23,331 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2013-08-16 09:02:23,386 INFO org.mortbay.log: Extract jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25-2.3.12.3.fc19.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar!/webapps/hdfs to /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_50070_hdfs____w2cu08/webapp
2013-08-16 09:02:25,171 WARN org.mortbay.log: failed jsp: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory
2013-08-16 09:02:25,215 WARN org.mortbay.log: failed org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@12305d34{/,jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25-2.3.12.3.fc19.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar!/webapps/hdfs}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory
2013-08-16 09:02:25,225 WARN org.mortbay.log: failed ContextHandlerCollection@25370a40: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory
2013-08-16 09:02:25,226 ERROR org.mortbay.log: Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:99)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:736)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:638)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:517)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:395)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more
2013-08-16 09:02:25,307 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070
2013-08-16 09:02:25,307 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:rlk cause:java.io.IOException: Problem in starting http server. Server handlers failed
2013-08-16 09:02:25,308 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070
2013-08-16 09:02:25,308 ERROR org.mortbay.log: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.destroy(JspServlet.java:282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.destroyInstance(ServletHolder.java:318)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStop(ServletHolder.java:289)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doStop(ServletHandler.java:185)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStop(HandlerWrapper.java:142)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStop(HandlerWrapper.java:142)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.doStop(SessionHandler.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStop(HandlerWrapper.java:142)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:592)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:537)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStop(HandlerCollection.java:169)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStop(HandlerWrapper.java:142)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStop(Server.java:283)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.stop(HttpServer.java:688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.stop(NameNode.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
2013-08-16 09:02:25,336 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicationMonitor thread received InterruptedExceptionjava.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2013-08-16 09:02:25,337 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DecommissionManager: Interrupted Monitor
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DecommissionManager$Monitor.run(DecommissionManager.java:65)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2013-08-16 09:02:25,339 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 0 Total time for transactions(ms): 0 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 0 SyncTimes(ms): 0 
2013-08-16 09:02:25,375 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: closing edit log: position=4, editlog=/home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/edits
2013-08-16 09:02:25,375 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: close success: truncate to 4, editlog=/home/rlk/hduser/dfs/name/current/edits
2013-08-16 09:02:25,403 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8020
2013-08-16 09:02:25,411 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcInstrumentation: shut down
2013-08-16 09:02:25,412 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: Problem in starting http server. Server handlers failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:517)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:395)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)

2013-08-16 09:02:25,413 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at localhost.lan/192.168.1.94
************************************************************/
```

I also give you my hadoop configuration (I'm using hadoop-1.2.1) :

core-site.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!-- core-site.xml -->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/rlk/hduser</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!-- hdfs-site.xml -->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!-- mapred-site.xml -->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:8021</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution : it was some jar collisions. I had duplicate jar files both in `hadoop-x.y.z/` and `hadoop-x.y.z/lib and in path-to-java/jre/lib/ext/`.

I just removed the formers and everything works fine again.

Answer (score 1):

you did not mention port number for master node in `core-site.xml`.

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://master:port</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Pseudo-distributed configuration,  fs.default.name even without port num 'll work as per hadoop-1.0.4/src/core/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

this problem in core-site.xml please set proper

```
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/rlk/hduser</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost/90000</value>
  </property>
```