# Hadoop - NameNode shuts itself down

Tags: hadoop

Running on Ubuntu 14.04 (AWS) + Hadoop 2.4.0, NameNode is shutting itself down so frequently after I log out from my HDuser account. Five other processes (which can be seen on JPS) run well.

How to prevent from shutting down?

Comment: Did you check the namenode logs?

Comment: The only thing I focused on was 'Starting services required for active state'.

Answer (score 0):

Format HDFS:

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076439/namenode-not-getting-started/8077772).