# NameNode shuts down itself after starting the hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I have installed **hadoop 1.2.1** on linux with single node cluster configuration. It was running fine and the `jps` command was displaying the information of all 5 jobs

- JobTracker
- NameNode
- TaskTracker
- SecondaryNameNode
- jps
- DataNode.`

Now, when I start the hadoop using command `bin/start-all.sh`, hadoop starts all 5 jobs but within few seconds namenode shuts down itself.

Any ideas how can I solve this issue?

I have checked the namenode log file and it shows the following error:

```
 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: Edit log corruption detected: corruption length = 98362 > toleration length = 0; the corruption is intolerable.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is been asked many times and answered as well, searching with the exception message would give you the results.
Before asking questions in Stackoverflow, please check for same kind of question is asked earlier by search option at top right corner.
coming to the problem statement,
It was most probably due to the `hadoop.tmp.dir` where your namenode stores the edit logs and and check point data.
After every reboot of your machine, `tmp` folder will be cleared by many services which causing the problem while trying to access by namenode again.
so only the length is 0 after you reboot it.
in `core-site.xml` change the property `hadoop.tmp.dir` directory to other directory.
Reference is : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076439/namenode-not-getting-started/8077772)
Hope it helps!

Comment: I have already tried your suggested solutions. The only thing remaining to try is to format the namenode. I have alot of data on it and I was looking for the solution that can still save my data.

Comment: You no longer can get the data from the `temp` folder after rebooting the machine.if your checkpoint director is not `temp` then you can get your data back from the fsImage in that folder.