# Cannot open hadoop Web UI localhost:50070

Tags: hadoop

I had installed hadoop 2.7.1 on my Ubuntu 14.04.After installing when i ran the jps command it showed the following :

sukalyan@sukalyan-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ jps

7601 NodeManager

7464 ResourceManager

7921 Jps

7292 SecondaryNameNode

7099 DataNode

It can be clearly seen that the namenode is missing ,hence when I run localhost:50070 on my browser ,it shows 'problem loading page'.I went through many solutions but none of them worked unfortunately.What may be wrong and how do I make the namenode to run? Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076439/namenode-not-getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially my localhost was set at 9000,which I think was already occupied for some reason. I changed it to another location 54310 and now my namenode seems to work like wonders !

Answer (score -1):

Try to add following to your hdfs-site.xml.

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>/home/username/pseudo/dfs/name</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>/home/user/pseudo/dfs/data</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Have you restarted cluster after changing this configuration?

Comment: Yes I did ! It is fixed by the way ! Thanks for answering :)

Comment: @DhruvKapatel,can I set 'dfs.name.dir' and 'dfs.data.dir' to any folder?