# Name node is not displaying when I hit JPS

Tags: hadoop

Contents of hdfs.site.xml :

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
```

`jps` is not starting namenode

```
   20471 NodeManager
    20515 Jps
    20036 DataNode
    20362 ResourceManager
```

Comment: can you post your namenode startup logs

Comment: Please tellme how do i need to do that...since i m new to hadoop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076439/namenode-not-getting-started