# Hadoop Name Node Format

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I realized I mis-configured my Hadoop ecosystem. I need to format the namenode, but I don't want to lose all the data that I currently have in hdfs.

How do I format my namenode without losing everything in hdfs.

Thanks

Comment: Seems drastic... What do you mean "mis-configured"? Formatting the namenode will remove the block pointers, yes, but the datanodes hold the actual data.

Comment: i essentially had a situation like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076439/namenode-not-getting-started. However they keep talking about formating the namenode when this happens. If I do that I will lose the data in hdfs

Comment: What exactly did you change in the XML configs? How much data do you have in HDFS?

Comment: Do you wanna move the HDFS data to another cluster???